# Interaction of Invoke Duplicity and Misty Step

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, cleric

Can you teleport farther away with *misty step* if you have a double from Invoke Duplicity? The Channel Divinity feature says:

> you can cast spells as though you were in the illusion's space, but
>   you must use your own senses. (PHB 63)

If you were where your duplicate is, you could *step* to a space 30ft from its position. So if it is 60ft from you, you could teleport to a space 90ft from your actual position. But the spell says that:

> you teleport up to 30 feet (PHB 260)

This would put a hard limit on the distance you can travel.

Which rule takes precedence here?

Answer (score 14):

While you have spells that say:

> Range: self
>
> you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

And:

> Cast as if you were in the illusions space

You then cast the spell(Misty Step) on your *self* (who from the spell's perspective is in the space of the illusion thanks to Invoke Duplicity).  As long as you can see the space that you want to "step" to, and it is within 30 feet of the illusion, that would indeed mean you can "step" there in this manner.

Comment: The logic is good, but your last paragraph's first sentence is a little clunky.  Could you revise it to be a bit clearer?  I gave it a try but maybe I misunderstood your intent.

Answer (score -1):

Since Misty Step targets Self, I would argue that you can only move 30' even if the spell seems to be coming from 60' away.  It is still targeting you and allows you to move 30' form your current position (not from the spell origin).  Although it might be valid to have the illusion target itself, but I think that is a stretch.

Comment: "as if you were in the illusions sapce" means that your self, for spell casting reasons, would be in the illusions space. You'd still be casting on your self, you'd just be doing it as if you were in the illusions space -- you know like the class ability lets you do. :)

Comment: You can cast spells as if in the illusion's space is different from effecting you as if you are in the illusion's space.  If you could be in 2 places at once (which is not what the feature says it does), then why would it limit your senses to where you actually are vs where the illusion is?  For instance, if your illusion is at an intersection, you couldn't even cast spells around the corner down the other hallway because you would have no line of sight, despite having a line of effect.

Answer (score -2):

I think RAI here is to Invoke Duplicity affect spells that originate from the caster, but affect other creatures (such as lightning bolt, burning hands, etc.). So if you cast a spell with range of "self" through the duplicate, then, as a DM, I would rule that the duplicate and the caster would each teleport 30ft.

When the authors wrote "but you must use your own senses" they clearly intended to avoid abuse, such as casting a fireball from behind a corner. Allowing for a 90ft misty step seems more broken then casting offenseive spells from corners.

Answer (score -4):

Ultimately, what it comes down to is this: you're not just in that space for the purposes of range, you're in that space for all purposes. Like, if you *wall of fire* the illusion as the illusion, you take damage.

Invoke Duplicity alters how other spells work, so that you can use them as if you were in that space.  This includes *Misty Step* and any other range limited spells.  You're still only teleporting 30 feet, as far as the spell's concerned, because you're in the duplicate's space.  Basically, Invoke Duplicity tries to let you be in two places at once, sort of, by letting you count as being in either place when you cast a spell. Note that using any sort of teleport will give away which of you is the real one, since there's no way for your duplicate to teleport.

Comment: The whole problem is that misty step has a range of *self*. The distance limitation is in the description itself. Also, for teleporting to give me away, the observer would have to know how the duplicate actually works.

Comment: @Szega I think what the answer is trying to say is it turns into "you teleport up to 30ft (as though you were in the illusion's space)" which is your first interpretation.

Comment: Right, you're not just in that space for the purposes of range, you're in that space for *all* purposes.  Like, if you *wall of fire* the illusion as the illusion, you take damage.

Comment: Your interpretation of wall of fire is simply not correct. The wall appears *after* you cast it and thus it does not matter that you cast it through the double. And it would be ridiculous too...

Comment: @Szega anyone occupying a space the wall occupies takes damage when it's cast, not just after.  If you don't like how the ability works, you are free to change it, but as written you and the duplicate are very much linked and it is by no means *just* an illusion.

Comment: Yes, nothing in the description of _Invoke Duplicity_ indicates that you are damaged by spells (cast by you or not) that affect the space your duplicate is in. It only affects how you _cast_ spells.

Comment: I disagree with the wall of fire,  but invoke duplicity would allow you to cast say destructive wave from the location of the duplicate (range of self).