# Misty Step and Manifest Mind Order of scribes

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard, teleportation

The Order of Scribe's wizard's level 6 feature Manifest Mind (TCoE, p.78) states (emphasis mine):

> Whenever you cast a wizard spell on your turn, **you can cast it as if you were in the spectral mind's space**, **instead of your own, using its senses**. You can do so a number of times per day equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

So the way I read it you could cast *misty step* from the Manifest Mind space, the problem is that it can be up to 300ft away from the wizard's position, allowing me to *misty step* up to 330ft. Is this right?

Comment: Very related, does this answer your question: "[Interaction of Invoke Duplicity and Misty Step](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110039)"